# Unable to resolve reference to Class loaded via External library

Tags: mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule4

I am using Anypoint studio  7.9
Mule runtime 4.3

I have class with static method as a package jar. I have added the same via Configure build path external library (not in pom xml or mule artifact json)
While invoking static method I am getting from Datweave

```
Unable to resolve module with identifier (package name)
```

Has anyone faced similar issue

PS : I have another similar jar and method. I have added via pom xml and it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Studio 7.x projects are Maven based. While you can edit the build path in the UI, that doesn't update the pom.xml, and cause libraries to be missed at build time. Don't configure build path and always use the pom.